# How to find the admin of a Facebook page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-apps

Is there anyway of finding the admin of a Facebook page by using JavaScript, Browser Addon or a piece of software?

Comment: If you know their websites, and they happen to gather insight through facebook, you could look for the tag `meta` with `fb:admins`, that's the user id

Comment: There is no website of the page i'm seeking to. It's just a community page.

Comment: you can search for the user who comments the most, talks the most and likes the most from the beginning of the page , maybe you will get lucky. ps: dont forget about comments and pictures and post by others

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no API. There is no hidden admin in the source. You just can't get the admin of a  facebook page if the person choose to stay anonymous.

This "question" probably also does not belong to SO.

Comment: Is it impossible to find the admin with a java script? :(

Comment: Seriously?! It is impossible. Neither with Javascript nor with any other programming language.

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to know fb admin by js...as their is no API for that...